# I need to compare 2 Row Table value with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, iteration

I am new to React js.

I made table with React js. and example picture is following

[image]

I want compare each column's value. For example, 1 with 10 (a column), 2 with 20 (b column), 30 with 5(column c). then want to add css change.

but i cannot find the way to do that. please help me

my code is following.

```
// Table Main code
// Maintable code

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TableRow from "./TableRow"
import './ManageTable.css'


const ManageTable = (props) => {
    const headerMeta = ['a','b','c'
    ];

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([{ a: 1,b:2,c :30 },{ a: 10,b:20,c :5 },]);

    return (
        <>
       
        <div>
            {tableData.length !== 0 && (
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                   {headerMeta.map(i=><th>{i}</th>)}
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {tableData.map((d, i) => {
                    return (<TableRow key={i} data={d}/>);
                }
                )}
                                
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            )}
        </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default ManageTable
```

```
//Row code file

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './TableRow.css'

const TableRow = ({ key, data}) => {
    const [RowData, setRowData] = useState(data);

    return (
                <>
        <tr key={key}>
            <td>{RowData.a}</td>
            <td>{RowData.b}</td>
            <td>{RowData.c}</td>
              
        </tr>
        </>
    )
};


export default TableRow;
```

Please help me

Comment: is the css change you want to make has two states? e.g if the tabledata[0].a ===  tabledata[1].a  than true or false?

if true than make certain color change or dont change anything at all.

give more info.

Comment: Yes, that's all i need. i want to compare value of each column. then want to change background or font color of cell. Thanks for reply

Comment: let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see, there is a change function that handles the logic.
you need to have if else there to send true flag to alterCssChange

alterCssChange can decide what css goes.

```js
var change = (index) => {
    // if you want to change the first row than the index would be 0.

    if(index === 1) {
        //write code to compare 
        if(tableData[0].a === tableData[1].a){
            // you can addd your logic here.
            // return a flag true or false   
        }
    }
  }
  
  return (.......
  
    {
        tableData.map((d, i) => {
            return <TableRow key={i} data={d} alterCssFlag={change(i)} />;
        })
    }
  
  )
  
  
  const TableRow = ({ key, data,alterCssFlag}) => {
  // use alterCssFlag to change the css in the elements below
    const [RowData, setRowData] = useState(data);

    return (
        <>
          <tr key={key}>
              <td>{RowData.a}</td>
              <td>{RowData.b}</td>
              <td>{RowData.c}</td>      
          </tr>
        </>
    )
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work. if i follow your code, then 1st and 2nd row are changed. i want to change only one of 2 line.

Comment: Cool than you write a simple condition that if index is 1 than return true plus additional condition to change the colour, I will update the code in a while

Comment: @omaeya I have just changed the index from 0 to 1 which will return true only if the index is 1, in all other conditions it will be false and hence you can control for index 1